# Show multiple histograms of images

Tags: python, matplotlib, computer-vision, histogram

I have 4 images, and I'm trying to show their histograms in one figure with 4 subplots.

I've debugged it and the `img` value that is assigned always changes, I'm not sure why the first image's histogram overrides all the other histograms.

The end result is that it shows me the same histogram 4 times instead.

```
img_path_fldr = '/home/some_folder'
files_lst = os.listdir(img_path_fldr)
img_lst = [x for x in files_lst if x.endswith('jpg') or x.endswith('.png')]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

for row in ax:
    for col in row:
        color = ('b')
        for j, col1 in enumerate(color):
            for i in img_lst:
                img = cv.imread(os.path.join(img_path_fldr, i))
                histr = cv.calcHist([img], [j], None, [256], [0, 256])
                col.plot(histr, color=col1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The way your loop goes, in every ax you are doing the same thing (reading the images and calculating the histogram). So in every subplot you are plotting the same thing, the histogram for your last image. You need to rewrite your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow your succession of for-loops. It seems to me the code below would do what your want

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

for ax, file in zip(axes.flat, img_lst):
    img = cv.imread(os.path.join(img_path_fldr, file))
    histr = cv.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
    ax.plot(histr, color=col1)

plt.show()
```